# Only one cancellation law? Then $G$ may not be a group...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that the following result is known:

**"Let $G$ be a *finite* set, closed with respect to an associative product and that both of the cancellation laws are valid. Then $G$ is a group with respect to this product."**

The question is: "Find a counter-example which shows that, if one supposes only one of the cancellation laws, then we can't to conclude that $G$ is a group."

Cancellation laws:
$$ax=ay \implies x=y$$
$$xa=ya \implies x=y$$

Which is this counter-example?! I can't find it!! Need some help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $xy=x$ for all $x,y\in G$. This operation is associative and satisfies the right cancellation law but not the left.

Comment: Thank you very much @Brian M. Scott. You really saved me. ;)

Comment: @Anderson: You’re welcome!